# Use node.js pg-postgres module to add multiple rows to postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have an array that looks like this in Node.js

```
let userData = [
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 25
},
{
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Mark",
    "age": 20
}
```

]

I need to insert this data into a postgreSQL table named users and if user_id already exists update the data.  What I am currently doing using the pg-postgres client is:

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const dbClient = new Client(credentials);

await dbClient.connect();

for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
    await dbClient.query(`INSERT INTO users('user_id' , 'name' , 'age') VALUES(
        '${userData[i].user_id}','${userData[i].name}','${userData[i].age}')
        ON CONFLICT(user_id) DO UPDATE SET name = '${userData[i].name}',age = '${userData[i].age}';`)
}
```

This works but I was wondering if there was some better way to insert the data into the DB rather than looping through each item in the array or is it the best way?